# Cannot connect to HBase from WildFly

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, hbase, wildfly

I've encountered strange problem while trying to connect to HBase 0.98.5-hadoop2 database from EJB deployed onto WildFly 8.1.0.Final.

This code works perfectly as standalone application:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   Configuration config = getConfiguration();
   HConnection connection = HConnectionManager.createConnection(config);
} 
private static Configuration getConfiguration() {
   Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
   config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "hbase");  // 
   config.set("hbase.client.retries.number", "3");  // 
   config.set("hbase.cluster.distributed", "true");
   return config;
}
```

but when I include it into EJB and run from server I've got following exception:

> 2014-10-09 11:58:57,737 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (EJB
>   default - 2) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component
>   HbaseExecutorImpl for method public abstract void
>   hbasetest.HbaseExecutor.testConnect(): javax.ejb.EJBException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: failure to login     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190)
>   [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
>   [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:340)
>   [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
>   [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:79)
>   [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
>   [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
>   [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95)
>   [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
>   [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)
>   [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55)
>   [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:448)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:330)
>   [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.access$100(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:70)
>   [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler$1.run(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:203)
>   [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: failure to login     at
>   hbasetest.HbaseExecutorImpl.testConnect(HbaseExecutorImpl.java:21)
>   [db2test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
>   [wildfly-weld-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
>   [wildfly-weld-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
>   [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
>   [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]     at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
>   [wildfly-weld-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
>   [wildfly-ee-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
>     at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.processInvocation(NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.java:59)
>   [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:273)
>   [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]    ... 39 more Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: failure to login     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:700)
>   [hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar:]    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:571)
>   [hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar:]    at
>   hbasetest.HbaseExecutorImpl.testConnect(HbaseExecutorImpl.java:19)
>   [db2test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]   ... 74 more Caused by:
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule
>   class: com.sun.security.auth.module.NTLoginModule from [Module
>   "com.something.hbaseclient:main" from local module loader @64f40c1f
>   (finder: local module finder @5247fb00 (roots:
>   C:\opt\dtv\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\modules,C:\opt\dtv\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
>     at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:800)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:690)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:688)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:687)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:595)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:675)
>   [hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar:]    ... 76 more

Same happens on Linux machines except for it's UnixLoginModule it can't find.

Actual exception happens on this line from org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User

```
private SecureHadoopUser() throws IOException {
   ugi = UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser();
}
```

Very simple EJB code illustrating the subject follows. It fails no matter HBase server exists or not.

```
package hbasetest;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;
@Stateless
public class HbaseExecutorImpl implements HbaseExecutor {
    public void test() {
        try {
            UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I've set up HBase client as a module, here's module.xml content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.something.hbaseclient">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="activation-1.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="aopalliance-1.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="asm-3.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="avro-1.7.7.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-cli-1.2.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-codec-1.7.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-collections-3.2.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-compress-1.4.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-configuration-1.6.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-digester-1.8.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-httpclient-3.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-io-2.4.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-lang-2.6.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-math-2.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="commons-net-3.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="findbugs-annotations-1.3.9-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="guava-12.0.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="guice-3.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="guice-servlet-3.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hbase-client-0.98.5-hadoop2.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hbase-common-0.98.5-hadoop2.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hbase-protocol-0.98.5-hadoop2.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="htrace-core-2.04.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="javax.inject-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jersey-core-1.8.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jersey-guice-1.9.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jersey-json-1.8.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jersey-server-1.8.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jets3t-0.6.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jettison-1.3.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jetty-6.1.26.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jetty-util-6.1.26.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jsch-0.1.42.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jsr305-1.3.9.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="netty-3.6.6.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="paranamer-2.3.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="xmlenc-0.52.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="xz-1.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="zookeeper-3.4.6.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javaee.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml looks like this:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.something.hbaseclient"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I'd like to know what happens. It seems code residing on WildFly has wrong security context and hence some WildFly settings should be helpful but I really got no idea what to do for now.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone's interested I've fixed this issue with adding this

```
<system export="true">
   <paths>
      <path name="com/sun/security/auth/module"/>
   </paths>
</system>
```

into  section of module.xml

It has to be added to module.xml and not into jboss-deployment-structure.xml due to way WildFly loads classes.